# Dynamical system equilibrium point increment

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

I am reading through the dynamical systems theory and there is an example of a Mass-Spring system. The state equations are given by

$\displaystyle \frac{d x_1}{dx}(t) = x_2(t)$

$\displaystyle \frac{d x_2}{dx}(t) = \frac{-k}{m}x_1(t)+\frac{f(t)}{m}$

Then we find the equilibrium point by setting

$\displaystyle 0 = x_2(t)$

$\displaystyle 0 = \frac{-k}{m}x_1(t)+\frac{f(t)}{m}$

Which gives as result

$x_{eq} =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
f/k \\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right]$

Finally, the book defines the increment with respect to the equilibrium point $\Delta x(t) = x(t) - x_{eq}$. Substracting equation (1,3) and (2,4) the result is

$\displaystyle \frac{d \Delta x_1}{dx}(t) = \Delta x_2(t)$

$\displaystyle \frac{d \Delta x_2}{dx}(t) = \frac{-k}{m}\Delta x_1(t)$

So far so good, but for the next step they get "the general solution, parametrized by the initial state" as

$\displaystyle \Delta x_1(t) = \Delta x_1(0) cos(\omega t) + \frac{\Delta x_2(0)}{\omega} sin(\omega t)$

$\displaystyle \Delta x_2(t) = -\Delta x_1(0) \omega sin(\omega t) + \Delta x_2(0)cos(\omega t)$

This result I don't understand where does it comes from, could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ODE business, the solution of :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dx_1}{dt} &=& x_2\\
\frac{dx_2}{dt} &=& -\frac{k}{m} x_1
\end{eqnarray*}
is of the form you wrote. Let $\omega^2 = \frac{k}{m}$ for simplification.

A way to prove it is to differentiate the first equation and substitute the second in: $$\frac{d^2x_1}{dt^2} = \frac{dx_2}{dt} = -\omega^2 x_1$$

So the solution for $x_1$ is of the form : $$x_1(t) = A_1\cos(\sqrt{\omega}t) + A_2\sin(\sqrt{\omega}t)$$

Differentiate it to find the solution to $x_2(t)$.

Then substituting the initial conditions you find $A_1 = x_1(0)$ and $A_2 = \frac{x_2(0)}{\omega}$.